# Skimage Image Segmentation

Tags: python, image-segmentation, scikit-image

I have a bunch of SEM images that I'm trying to segment to search for features. This is one of those things that's obvious to a person looking at it but less so to a computer (at least one coded by me!). I was hoping that someone might give me a way to think about these kinds of problems and this one in particular.

So here's an easy example that works more or less whatever I do:
[image: good-raw]

I do some basic trimming to get rid of the meta-data (actually I read it first but that's btw). Then if I, for example, do:

```
import skimage.filters as filters
threshold = filters.threshold_isodata(image)
seg_image = image > threshold
```

I get a true/false array which can be viewed as an image and looks like this:

[image: good-segmented]

(I put a little black strip at the bottom so you can flick back and forth with pleasing effect).

However, the same code on this image:

[image: bad-raw]

leads to this result:

[image: bad-segmented]

It should be clear to any human reading this that it's got a lot of false positives. The background has been overexposed and has added a bunch of noise which then gets caught in the threshold.

I've tried various combinations of:

```
import skimage.segmentation as seg
import skimage.restoration as res
import skimage.filters as filters
import skimage.morphology as morph
seg_image = np.copy(image)
seg_image = morph.opening(seg_image, morph.disk(2))
seg_image = res.denoise_bilateral(seg_image)
seed = np.copy(seg_image)
seed[1:-1,1:-1] = seg_image.min()
seg_image = seg_image - morph.reconstruction(seed, seg_image)
```

As well as a few other filters (in different orders and including or excluding at random). I don't, in general, do all of those things because it's a disaster.

My logic, such as it is, was:

- opening is a way to get rid of small bright spots. A small disk could remove this little noise pixels in the bulk of the image.
- denoise_bilateral was a similar logic.
- the reconstruction is meant to remove backgrounds and leave only the foreground. Unfortunately this tended to include the noisy pixels.

I'm continuing to fiddle around, but I'd love to know thoughts on these kinds of "gray on gray" images. But I really want to understand a better approach.

---

Update: Canny edge detection seems to work quite uncannily.

Good image:
[image: good-canny]

Bad image:
[image: bad-canny]

Now the challenge is to count the stuff inside these edges. The hole filling approach from [here](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/applications/plot_coins_segmentation.html?highlight=segmentation) (using from scipy import ndimage as ndi , ndi.binary_fill_holes(seg_image)) fails because it fills the wrong areas. But this seems like a good approach.

Comment: Lots of approaches here, but, yes, your first and second image are like night and day, so it's tricky to generalise one approach. =) (1) Have a look at the [shape index](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.feature.html#skimage.feature.shape_index), which lets you characterise ridges in an image; (2) Have a look at [attribute operators](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/filters/plot_attribute_operators.html), which let you separate long skinny things from spots;

Comment: and (3) btw, I wrote an FEI tiff reader for imageio which grabs the metada and discards the watermark: https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/format_fei.html =) `imageio.imread(filename, format='fei')`